# Getting "Unsupported major.minor version 52.0" exception while using Spark Web Application framework

Tags: java, spark-java

Getting following exception:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: spark/Route : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0

trying to use spark web application framework, when I execute file, it throws this exception.

Spark Framework version: 2.0.0

Comment: I could resolve my problem by decreasing version of Spark Framework that I was using

Earlier i was using Spark Framework version : 2.0.0

Degraded version to 1.1.1

And it worked.

Hope other people will find it useful.

Comment: Increasing the jdk/jre version it uses would also work.

Comment: In my case had multiple jdks, so just needed to set JAVA_HOME to 1.8

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are using Java files, compiled with Java 8 (version 52.0) and a JRE which does not support it (so Java < version 8)

Comment: this isn't a solution, more of a comment?

Comment: Yeah. The actual solution is implicit and mentioned in the comments above. So no need to add it here again, BTW this question is marked "This question already has an answer here:".